# How to safely delete rows in a shared Google Sheets document with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My Sheets document receives rows from Google Forms submissions. Currently I have Apps Script that processes these rows and generates new rows based on the initial 'raw' row. After generating the new rows, I'd like to delete the initial row but I don't know how to do that safely. I tried generating an ID for each initial row and then delete the row based on that, but the ID may be added to a wrong row if users filter or move the rows at the same time the script is running.

On a broader note, is it safe to use Apps Script on Sheets documents that are shared among several users who may edit the document by adding, deleting or modifying rows?

Comment: My opinion is to leave linked sheets alone and construct customized versions from the onFormSubmit trigger for the Spreadsheet and leave the linked sheet alone to serve as a backup of the  data received in the event object.  As far as the rest of your question, it's up to you. Do you trust them or not?  It's totally up to you.  If my clients are engineers I trust them.  If they're not I don't. That's my opinion.

Comment: Agree with @Cooper `leave linked sheets alone` and use a different sheet for any modifications(That should be posted as answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using the onFormSubmit trigger in a Spreadsheet

```
function onformsubmit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 
  e.values().length).setValues([e.values]);
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [onFormSubmit(e) Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)